# Out of memory in SOAPMessage countAttachments API

Tags: java, web-services, soap, out-of-memory

SOAP message has been constructed from HttpServletRequest's input stream with API

```
SOAPMessage message = messageFactory.createMessage(soapHeader, 
                           request.getInputStream());
```

When max memory allotted to the process is -Xmx1024m and when memory snapshot of the process shown 100m, the following call

```
message.countAttachments()
```

threw out of memory exception

Platform: Windows 7 64bit, Java JDK1.6 update 25

Comment: What language and platform is this? PHP?

Comment: Edited the post for these details

Answer (score 0):

message object was instanceof

```
com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.Message1_1Impl
```

This object has been created by

```
com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPMessageFactory1_1Impl
```

Shifting message factory to

```
org.apache.axis.soap.MessageFactoryImpl
```

resolved it.